# How to capture the URL used to launch an OS X application via URLScheme in Swift?

Tags: macos, swift, xcode6

I've been trying to replicate the usual way of doing this in Objective-C in Swift for a new swift app I'm playing around with.

How to do this in Objective-C is well documented, you get the shared apple event manager and call `setEventHandler` method to register a function as the handler for the event class `kInternetEventClass` with the event id `kAEGetURL`.

So in swift I'm trying to do the same thing with this code added to the template AppDelegate.swift inside a brand new project:

```
func applicationWillFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
    var appleEventManager:NSAppleEventManager = NSAppleEventManager.sharedAppleEventManager()
    appleEventManager.setEventHandler(self, andSelector: "handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:", forEventClass: kInternetEventClass, andEventID: kAEGetURL)
}

func handleGetURLEvent(event: NSAppleEventDescriptor?, replyEvent: NSAppleEventDescriptor?) {
    println("yay");
}
```

As far as I can tell this is just a syntax conversion of the standard Objective-c call.  But I get a type error for both the `forEventClass` and `andEventId` arguments to the `setEventHandler` method:

`'NSNumber' is not a subtype of 'AEEventClass'` for the `forEventClass` argument

and:

`'NSNumber' is not a subtype of 'AEEventId'` for the `andEventID` argument

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong at this stage as both `kInternetEventClass` and `kAEGetURL` are constants defined by apple...  Surely I'm not required to convert their `NSNumber` type to their respective required types?  And if I am I can't work out how.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the documentation the classes takes the constant and converts it to the proper type:

```
func applicationWillFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
    var appleEventManager:NSAppleEventManager = NSAppleEventManager.sharedAppleEventManager()
    appleEventManager.setEventHandler(self, andSelector: "handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:", forEventClass: AEEventClass(kInternetEventClass), andEventID: AEEventID(kAEGetURL))
}
```

Comment: If anyone actually knows what's happening here and what the proper terminology is, please edit my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yep thanks, this seems to work - does feel strange that this is required though.

Comment: Worth mentioning that your selector string should be "handleGetURLEvent:replyEvent:" to correctly match the Swift func declaration above.

Answer (score 1):

I found that as of Xcode 8.2 I needed to convert MagerValp's code to the following:

```
func applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    let aem = NSAppleEventManager.shared();
    aem.setEventHandler(self, andSelector: Selector(("handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:")), forEventClass: AEEventClass(kInternetEventClass), andEventID: AEEventID(kAEGetURL))
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get an error in console.app when I try to open my app via the custom url: `-[MyApp.AppDelegate handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60c0000039b0` (I've named the second param in handleGetURLEvent `withReplyEvent`). Any idea? Using Xcode 8.3.3 (8E3004b)

Comment: The solution, which was given on my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065842/open-cocoa-app-via-url-scheme, is to replace `Selector(("handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:"))` with the new style selector: `#selector(AppDelegate.handleGetURLEvent(event:replyEvent:))`