# How to pass arguments from a custom-schema link to a Mac app registered to open links with that schema?

Tags: macos, browser

If in Xcode I set an URL type for my App:

[image: URL Types in Xcode]

Once it's open for first time, it register to all browsers that it will handle links of the type `myappx://something`.

Is it is suppose to call MyApp with "something" as argument? How do I read "something" from the run app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture the URL used to launch an OSX application via URLScheme in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080210/how-to-capture-the-url-used-to-launch-an-osx-application-via-urlscheme-in-swift)

Comment: I've found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080210/how-to-capture-the-url-used-to-launch-an-osx-application-via-urlscheme-in-swift